# Counting problem k-tuples

Tags: combinatorics

Let two k-tuples are said to be "2-different" if it is differ from at least two positions otherwise called  2-same . Which means (1,2,3,4) is 2-same with (1,2,3,5)  and (6,2,3,4).

Now let we have 3  numbers for each coordinate of k-tuple than there are at most 3^k different k- tuples can be formed.

My question is if  we have 3 numbers for each coordinate of k- tuple than at most how many 2-different k- tuples can be possible?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  For instance, have you worked out the results for $k = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5$?  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Let  $A$ be a set of $k$-tuples such that each two distinct $k$-tuples of $A$ are $2$-different. Then for each two distinct $k$-tuples $(a_1,\dots,a_k)$ and $(b_1,\dots,b_k)$ of $A$, $k-1$-tuples  $(a_1,\dots,a_{k-1})$ and $(b_1,\dots,b_{k-1})$ are distinct. So $|A|\le |S^{k-1}|=3^{k-1}$, where $S$ is a set of all $k-1$-tuples.

Conversely, for each $k-1$ tuple $a=(a_1,\dots,a_{k-1})\in S^{k-1}$ let $f(a)$ be the unique number from $1$ to $3$ such that a sum $\sum_{i=1}^k a_k$ is divisible by $3$. It is easy to see that a set $A=\{(a,f(a)):a\in S^{k-1}\}$ consists of mutually $2$-different $k$-tuples.